How to modify the function in Table1 package to get a p value for ANOVA
I am using R markdown and trying to simulate the vignette for table1 package on the following link and using the melanoma2 data set.
The link: Using the table1 Package to Create HTML Tables of Descriptive Statistics (r-project.org)
I got the to the step of creating an extra column for example creating a column for the p value and creating the following function for the p value.
This function works on 2 variables only and it gives the p value for chisquare test for categorical variable or paired t test for numerical variables.
pvalue <- function(x, ...) {
    # Construct vectors of data y, and groups (strata) g
    y <- unlist(x)
    g <- factor(rep(1:length(x), times=sapply(x, length)))
    if (is.numeric(y)) {
        # For numeric variables, perform a standard 2-sample t-test
        p <- t.test(y ~ g)$p.value
    } else {
        # For categorical variables, perform a chi-squared test of independence
        p <- chisq.test(table(y, g))$p.value
    }
    # Format the p-value, using an HTML entity for the less-than sign.
    # The initial empty string places the output on the line below the variable label.
    c("", sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001)))
}

My question is : How to create a function to give the P value for ANOVA test between 3 or more groups?
I tried the same as a above but changed the table to create 3 groups for a numeric variable and changed the function as per the following but it did not work !.
pvalue <- function(x, ...) {
    # Construct vectors of data y, and groups (strata) g
    y <- unlist(x)
    g <- factor(rep(1:length(x), times=sapply(x, length)))
    if (is.numeric(y)) {
        # For numeric variables, perform a standard 2-sample t-test
        p <- t.test(y ~ g)$p.value
    } else {
        # For categorical variables, perform a chi-squared test of independence
        p <- chisq.test(table(y, g))$p.value
} else { 
# For more than 2 numeric variables, perform ANOVA test
p <- aov (table(y, g))$p.value
    }
    # Format the p-value, using an HTML entity for the less-than sign.
    # The initial empty string places the output on the line below the variable label.
    c("", sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001)))
}

How can I modify the function to give P value for ANOVA when there are 3 or more groups for the numeric variables?

Can you show us an example of calling the first function?

See on this link; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html

Maybe something like the following solves the problem.
The code where the t-test is performed is changed to check the number of levels of g first. If g has exactly 2 levels a t-test is performed, if not, an ANOVA is performed.
pvalue <- function(x, ...) {
  # Construct vectors of data y, and groups (strata) g
  y <- unlist(x)
  g <- factor(rep(1:length(x), times = lengths(x)))
  if (is.numeric(y)) {
    # For numeric variables, perform a standard 2-sample t-test
    if(nlevels(g) == 2L) {
      p <- t.test(y ~ g)$p.value
    } else if(nlevels(g) > 2L) {
      a <- aov(y ~ g) |> summary()
      p <- a[[1L]][["Pr(>F)"]][1L]
    } else stop("Factor with less than 2 levels.")
  } else if(is.character(y) || is.factor(y)){
    # For categorical variables, perform a chi-squared test of independence
    p <- chisq.test(table(y, g))$p.value
  } else { 
    # not implemented
    warning("Not implemented, returning NULL.")
    return(invisible(NULL))
  }
  # Format the p-value, using an HTML entity for the less-than sign.
  # The initial empty string places the output on the line below the variable label.
  c("", sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001)))
}

